# wordpress page redirecting to 1&1 domain creation landing page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am facing a strange issue.

I just replaced an old site with new wordpress site.

In old site the url was

http://www.domain.com/corporate.html

In new site the url is

http://www.domain.com/corporate/

When I hit the new site url then it goes to the domain landing page (This homepage was created automatically when you registered your 1&1 domain package or hosting package.)

But when I remove the front slash / from the url then it displays http://www.domain.com/corporate.html but without .html at the end of url so it becomes http://www.domain.com/corporate

I changed the permalink to page_id and it works fine. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's fixed. I removed all the files from root and did a fresh transfer. It worked.

Comment: might as well delete this...